# Optimized element delivery in a graph with limited node capacity

Tags: graph-theory

I am a beginner in Graph theory and I have the following problem:

I have a graph of $N$ nodes, that all are occupied by $\{m_i\}_{i=1}^{N}$
elements and have a capacity (maximal occupancy) of $\{\Omega_{i=1}^{N}\}$.

Now, the nodes try to send *some* of their elements to some other nodes according to a table $\Lambda$. I say "try" here, because they are only allowed to send the elements as long as the maximal occupancy of the receiver is not exceeded.
Otherwise, the elements exceeding the capacity are send back.

I am interested to understand, what the maximal number of successfully delivered elements is.

My problem is the following: If I start sequentially with one node and send its elements to all the receivers, the maximal occupancy might be exceeded, but they are also giving away elements, such that no problem occurs.

At some point, this might break, because even with giving away its outgoing elements, one node's capacity is exceeded because of too many incoming packages.

The packages may not be lost, hence they are sent back to the sender, which again might has to send back some packages, such that its capacity is not exceeded. This might lead to a series of other exceeding-problems and I have to correct all those problems by "back-tracing" each single packages path.

Is there a solution to the question, how many packages each node (and this number may be lower than their scheduled sendings) may send in order not to exceed any nodes capacity while optimizing the number of totally successfully delivered packages?

Is there a branch of Graph theory dealing with those delivery problems?

---

There may be a synchronized exchange of elements as specified in the comments below.

Comment: May I ask if all nodes act in a synchronized way (they all send their packages at the same time), or if they act in a sequential way (one after the other)? Also, when they send their packages, are they considered empty before their neighbors received them, or only when their packages arrived? For instance, if there are only two nodes with a link, with capacity 1, and having 1 package each, is it possible that they switch their packages? Showing an example of moving packages may make the question clearer.

Comment: Hey, they are allowed to act synchronized, that means they are allowed to switch packages. But it would be also interesting to know, how the result changes, when they are not allowed to synchronize!